# An easier way to print from a live CD than Puppy?

Tags: drivers, printing, livecd, puppy-linux

After several failed attempts to burn an Ubuntu CD to live boot from (they wouldn't boot, maybe because my CD burning software wouldn't burn slower than 4X speed?), I've managed to get a boot disc working with Puppy linux ("Slacko").

My next task is to figure out how to print. I have an HP PSC2410 printer.

The documentation on puppylinux.org provides some links, and I tried following the instructions [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html). Unfortunately, it appears python isn't installed in Puppy by default, as I got the error:

```
./hplip-install: line 2: python: command not found
```

when I ran the install with `sh hplip-3.13.4.run`

There's [quite a list of system requirements](http://hplipopensource.com/node/295) for installing the print drivers, so I wonder if I'm barking up the wrong tree by trying to use Puppy.

Might I be better having another try at getting Ubuntu working, or is there an easier distribution to use that will enable me to print when booting from a live CD? The only functionality I need is print capability, a browser, and being able to read a flash drive, all offline from the web.

Comment: That error means that python isn't installed. Given you're a novice I'd be inclined to steer you towards either Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Comment: @slm, put that as an answer and I'll accept it. I have since managed to boot from Mint and print, though I did need to replace my DVD drive to get it working! Maybe that was the problem in the first place when I tried Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that python isn't installed. Given you're a novice I'd be inclined to steer you towards either Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Knoppix 7.7 works for me. Found my wifi and printer,(HP1514),effortlessly. Prints and scans perfectly.
Solydx also works.